# Draw offer without executing move

Tags: rules, draw

Scenario: It's Player A's move, and without executing a move he offers a draw. Player B replies "Please make a move". Player A then makes a move, where upon player B says: "Ok, I accept". Is it now possible for Player A to say that the draw offer no longer stands, and was in fact nullified when it was not originally accepted during the period between the offer and the move that Player A did?

Answer (score 10):

No, Player A cannot do this. FIDE rules of chess article 9.1.1:

> A player wishing to offer a draw shall do so after having made a move on the
>   chessboard and before stopping his clock and starting the opponent’s clock.
>   **An offer at any other time during play is still valid** but Article 12.6 must be
>   considered. No conditions can be attached to the offer. In both cases **the offer
>   cannot be withdrawn and remains valid until the opponent accepts it, rejects
>   it orally, rejects it by touching a piece with the intention of moving or
>   capturing it, or the game is concluded in some other way**.

Key parts highlighted. Player A made the draw offer at one of these "other times", so it's still valid and cannot be withdrawn. Player B asking player A to make a move, and player A actually making a move, are not one of the four actions that can terminate the draw offer, so the offer remains valid.

Comment: What if the move Player A made was to checkmate Player B?  I assume that would be covered under "the game is concluded in some other way" and thus the draw would automatically be rescinded?

Comment: @Michael To be honest I don't know, but it sounds like it, although obviously player B is going to accept before getting checkmated.

Comment: Checkmate immediately ends the game. You can't accept a draw offer after you've been mated. Stalemate also immediately ends the game.